# Scripts for listing all the distinct characters in a text file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

E.g.

Given a file `input.txt`, which has the following content:

```
He likes cats, really?
```

the output would be like:

```
H
e

l
i
k
s
c
a
t
,
r
l
y
?
```

Note the order of characters in output does not matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about:

```
echo "He likes cats, really?" | fold -w1 | sort -u
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `fold` doesn't work as expected with two-byte characters in UTF-8. It produces these characters � instead of needed ones. Presumably because it breaks these characters in two.

Comment: `grep -Eo '.{1}'` is unicode aware and does the same thing as `fold -w1`, so you can do:  `echo 'He likes , really?' | grep -Eo '.{1}' | sort -u`

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService I like it. Can you edit the answer to propose it as an alternative?

Comment: I got `"` and `[` twice for some reason. Chris' answer worked better for me.

Answer (score 19):

One way using `grep -o .` to put each character on a newline and  `sort -u` to remove duplicates:

```bsh
$ grep -o . file | sort -u
```

Or a solution that doesn't required `sort -u` or multiple commands written purely in `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!a[$i]++)print $i}' FS="" file
```

Answer (score 1):

An awk way:

```
awk  '{$1=$1}1' FS="" OFS="\n" file | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` as follows:

```
sed 's/./\0\n/g' input.txt | sort -u
```

Comment: Why characters are not replaced with null + new line? I mean they are still there.

Instead of `\0` one can also use `&` which is covered in sed manual. `&` reference the
whole matched portion of the pattern space. This works the same:

    `sed 's/./&\n/g' input.txt | sort -u`